# How to check if session array has an id which is unique when all retrieve value has same session key in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

Please i'm working on a quiz web app, i'm getting my data randomly from database and i'm saving it in a session array. now i want to check if the id of the retrieved data is in the session array if it is i want to generate a new value if is not in i want to push it to the array i have searched but not being  able to figure it out any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

This is what i did initially but the session exist is always returning true since i'm using same key;

```
 function random()
        {
            $output=DB::table('questions')->inRandomOrder()->first();
            return $output;
        }

        function checkRandomvalue($stored){

           if(session()->exists('question'))
              { 
                random();

              }

                session()->push('question',$stored);    
        }
        do{
            $r=random();
            $result=checkRandomvalue($r);
        }
        while($result);
```

And this is  what i did now checkRandomvalue function but this $question=session('question.0.id',[]); is returning null making the index to be always false

```
function checkRandomvalue($stored){

       $id=$stored->id;
       $question=session('question.0.id',[]);

       $index=array_search($id,$question);
        //dd($index);
       if($index==true)
          { 
              random();
          }
              $question[]=$id; 
              session()->put('question',$id);  
    }
```

Comment: what is `random();` ? it should be  $id = random(); instead?

Comment: try remove array[] from session second parameter

Comment: @daremachine thank you random() is a random call to the function that generates the random number.. and if i remove the [] as second parameter i get this error "array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given" because question would no longer be an array and array_search then throws the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem should incase anybody encounters same problem, i declared 2 session in the constructor one to store array and the second to hold session value not in the array so i can query my database with it

```
 public function __construct()
   {
    $this->middleware('auth');
       $val=[12];
       $rand=$val[0];
       Session::put('keys',$val);
       $value=session('keys');  
       Session::put('Key2',$rand);
       $v_random=session('Key2');
}
```

then this is method for my logic

```
    function random()
        {
            $output=DB::table('questions')->inRandomOrder()->first();
            return $output;
        }

        function checkRandomvalue($stored){
            global $value;
            global $v_random;
            $id=$stored->id;
            $value=session('keys');
            if(array_search($id,$value,true)==true) {

               return;

            }else if(array_search($id,$value,true)==false){
                Session::push('keys',$id);
                session()->save();
                $value=session('keys');
                Session::put('Key2',$id);
                //$v_random=session('Key2');
                //dd("good", $id, $value);
               //dd(session($key));;  
           }    
        } 
        do{

            $r=random();
            $result=checkRandomvalue($r);   
        }
        while($result);
       $v_random=session('Key2');
        $output=DB::table('questions')->where('id',$v_random)->get();
```